# Can protecting Trump cost $1m a day?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump

According to [CNN](http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/21/news/protecting-donald-trump/index.html):

> Protecting President-elect Donald Trump and his family is costing New York City more than $1 million a day, according to three city officials.

I have a hard time arriving to such a number even with very generous assumptions.

Am I missing something or is that an unrealistic claim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [a tweet](https://twitter.com/NYCMayor/status/805911254464393216) posted today by NYC's mayor, Bill de Blasio, the cost for protecting Trump between November 8th and January 20th is estimated at $35m, or approximately $500k per day.

The tweet's attachment is a letter detailing the protection that has been put in place.

This only includes the direct cost for protection and not indirect costs such as lost business.

Comment: It excludes Secret Service costs, so the number is likely higher.

Comment: I know it isn't part of the original question, but is this cost comparable to the cost of protecting previous presidential families?

Comment: @Oddthinking That's true, though the question was only asking about the cost to New York City. The Secret Service is federal, so part of their costs might come from NYC, but not directly.